# UIPanGestureRecognizer doesn't remember where the pan began

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a custom subclass of UIView, which has a UIPanGestureRecognizer and all the associated stuff it needs to handle it. The idea is that, depending on where the panning started from inside my view different things shall happen. Also I'll have to track the current position of the pan gesture later on. How do I properly set this up?

Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RangeSelectorView: UIView {

private let trackWidth: CGFloat = 3.0
private let thumbRadius: CGFloat = 10.0
private let trackOffset: CGFloat = 16

@IBInspectable let min: Int = 0
@IBInspectable let max: Int = 100
@IBInspectable var lowerThumbValue: Int = 0
@IBInspectable var upperThumbValue: Int = 100

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(trackTapped))
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(thumbDragged))
    addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let trackContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        trackContext.setLineWidth(trackWidth)
        trackContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
        trackContext.move(to: CGPoint(x: trackOffset, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        trackContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width
             - trackOffset, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        trackContext.strokePath()
    }
    if let thumbContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        let lowerRect = CGRect(x: trackOffset + getRelativeThumbPosition(for: lowerThumbValue) - thumbRadius, y: self.frame.height / 2 - thumbRadius, width: thumbRadius * 2, height: thumbRadius * 2)
        let upperRect = CGRect(x: trackOffset + getRelativeThumbPosition(for: upperThumbValue) - thumbRadius, y: self.frame.height / 2 - thumbRadius, width: thumbRadius * 2, height: thumbRadius * 2)
        thumbContext.addEllipse(in: lowerRect)
        thumbContext.addEllipse(in: upperRect)
        thumbContext.setFillColor(Constants.Colors.titleBlue.cgColor)
        thumbContext.fillPath()
    }
    if let highlightedRangeContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        highlightedRangeContext.setLineWidth(trackWidth)
        highlightedRangeContext.setStrokeColor(Constants.Colors.titleBlue.cgColor)
        highlightedRangeContext.move(to: CGPoint(x: trackOffset + getRelativeThumbPosition(for: lowerThumbValue) + thumbRadius, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        highlightedRangeContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: trackOffset + getRelativeThumbPosition(for: upperThumbValue) - thumbRadius, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        highlightedRangeContext.strokePath()
    }
}

private func getRelativeThumbPosition(for value: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let iterationDistance = (self.frame.width - trackOffset * 2) / CGFloat(max - min)
    return (CGFloat(value - min) * iterationDistance)
}

private func getTrackValue(for position: CGPoint) -> Int {
    let iterationDistance = (self.frame.width - trackOffset * 2) / CGFloat(max - min)
    return Int(position.x / iterationDistance)
}

@objc func trackTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var tappedValue = getTrackValue(for: recognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: self))
    if tappedValue > max {
        tappedValue = max
    } else if tappedValue < min {
        tappedValue = min
    }
    if tappedValue <= lowerThumbValue || tappedValue <= (upperThumbValue + lowerThumbValue) / 2 {
        lowerThumbValue = tappedValue
    } else {
        upperThumbValue = tappedValue
    }
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

@objc func thumbDragged(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .changed {
        if getTrackValue(for: recognizer.location(in: self)) <= (lowerThumbValue + upperThumbValue) / 2 {
            lowerThumbValue = getTrackValue(for: recognizer.translation(in: self))
        } else {
            upperThumbValue = getTrackValue(for: recognizer.translation(in: self))
        }
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        recognizer.setTranslation(recognizer.location(in: self), in: self)
    }
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

}

Everytime the function is called only the `lowerThumbValue` gets set. Also when a new pan gesture is started it 'hops' back to the initial value. What in detail am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What in detail am I doing wrong?" What in detail is your code? You have not shown what `lowerThumbValue` or `upperThumbValue` are, or what `getTrackValue` is. _Show your code_ if you want help. Explain what is happening and how that differs from what you intend to happen. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @matt these are Ints. `getTrackValue` turns the x-Value of a CGPoint into an Int

Comment: @Procra matt is referring to your explanation of the problem - it's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve and what your problem really is.. even my answer is just a guess in a way..

Comment: How on earth do you expect to get correct values if you are turning CGPoints into Ints? A CGPoint is made up of CGFloats. Turn it to an Int and you lose everything after the decimal point. Again: _show your code_ if you want help. I won't ask a third time.

Comment: @matt is this enough now?

Answer (score 1):

`translation(in:)` returns a relative change of the pan since the beginning, `location(in:)` should return a location of the touch in the coordinate system of the given view - use `location(in:)` to get the location in the view when the pan gesture begins.